# Index of a list in a nested for loop in python

Tags: python

I have a nested loop. I want to iterate on a list of lists and check if a parameter is in a list, bring me back the list index.

```
parameter="Abcd"
li1=["ndc","chic"]
li2=["Abcd","cuisck"]
Li=[li1,li2]
for i in Li:
    for j in i:
        if (parameter==j):
            x=i+1
print(x)
```

I expect an integer like for this example x=2.
But it does not work. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you expect `print(Area)`  to output? You never defined that name... And what do you expect `i+1` to be when `i` is a string?

Comment: Try to use `for j in range(len(i))` and you will get the index you want

Comment: Should the list your looping through be flattened? As it is youre getting the list the parameter belongs to but not the position in that list...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the output you are expecting, but I think you want something like this:

```
parameter="Abcd"
li1=["ndc","chic"]
li2=["Abcd","cuisck"]
Li=[li1,li2]
for row in Li:
    for i, j in enumerate(row):
        if parameter == j:
            print("List", Li.index(row),"Element", i)
```

Output:

```
List 1 Element 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate`, which returns the index and the element. Also use [sets](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), which are faster than lists (for long lists).

```
parameter = "Abcd"
lst1 = ["ndc", "chic"]
lst2 = ["Abcd", "cuisck"]
lst = [lst1, lst2]
x = None

for i, sublst in enumerate(lst):
    if parameter in set(sublst):
        x = i+1
print(x)
# 2
```

Comment: Sets are unordered and can't have duplicates, so they're not a drop in replacement, depending on exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Donnie: That's true, but for the exact problem in the OP sets are a good solution. If lists are preferred (perhaps for small lists), then simply use them like this: `if parameter in sublst:`

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy` array. It will save you tons of time and cost.

```
Li = np.array([li1,li2])

Li == parameter

array([[False, False],
       [ True, False]])

row, column = np.where(Li == parameter)

row
Out[17]: array([1], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parameter="Abcd"
li1=["ndc","chic"]
li2=["Abcd","cuisck"]
Li=[li1,li2]

index = -1

for i in Li:
    if parameter in i:
        index = Li.index(i)
            
print(index)
```

You can check if something is in a list with 'in' and get the index of the element with .index, it returns the integer position in the list.
Perhaps you want a tuple for the nested position ?
use something like `(Li.index(i), i.index(parameter))` as your return value.
Don't forget to declare your return value outside your loop scope !